# Encontrar valores duplicados y anularlos

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de ingresar una "X" cantidad de valores y que borre los valores que se repiten.

El problema es que no logro evitar que se borre el primer numero o que solo borre un repetido y el resto los deje.

Ej : Array de 5 espacios = 1 3 1 1 4
Resultado = 1 3 0 1 4

```
f_ingreso(int *almacen, int espacio)
{

    cout<<"Los valores que se repitan, no seran almacenados: ";

       //Ingresar un valor y compararlo, si se repite dar 0
int aux=1;


           for(int j = 0 ; j < espacio ; j++){// 1 3 1 4 5 Ingresando valores
                cin>>almacen[j];

           }
for(int i = 0 ; i < espacio ; i++)
{
    for(int j = 1 ; j < espacio ; j++)
    {
        if(almacen[i]==almacen[j])
        {
            aux++;
            if(aux>=2)
            {
                almacen[aux]=0;
                aux=0;

            }
        }
    }
}


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Si no necesitas usar tipos primitivos sugiero que uses las estructuras de STL, por ejemplo [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), o [`set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) si necesitas una estructura que solo permita elementos únicos.

Comment: Todavía no había visto nada sobre eso, investigare. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En muchas respuestas que he dado he hecho la misma recomendación: Usa nombres descriptivos en las variables.

Esta práctica permite que el código sea más legible y facilita la localización de errores.

Date cuenta que en `aux` llevas la cuenta de la cantidad de repetidos ... no de la posición de un elemento en cuestión. Los índices los controlas con `i` y `j`, luego deberías usar estas variables para borrar un elemento:

```
if(aux>=2)
{
    almacen[j]=0;
    aux=0;
}
```

Por otro lado, si en ese mismo condicial pones `aux` a 0 no vas a ser capaz de eliminar las apariciones *impares* (3, 5, 7, ...) ya que estas apariciones harán que `aux` valga `1`

```
if(aux>=2)
{
    almacen[j]=0;
}
```

De hecho no te hace falta `aux`. Si no quieres duplicados en cuanto encuentras una coincidencia la puedes eliminar directamente:

```
if(almacen[i]==almacen[j])
{
    almacen[j]=0;
}
```

Por cierto, nota que el segundo bucle no debe empezar en `1` sino en `i+1`

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < espacio ; i++)
{
    for(int j = i+1 ; j < espacio ; j++)
    {
    }
}
```

Los valores cuyo índice es inferior a `i` deberías considerarlos seguros y sin repeticiones

---

Si solo deseas eliminar únicamente la primera repetición de cada número necesitas un algoritmo un poco más complejo. Tienes que llevar al cuenta de qué números has borrado para no eliminar nuevas apariciones. Ten en  cuenta que en ante la secuencia:

```
1 3 1 1 1 4
```

La primera iteración va a eliminar el segundo `1`:

```
1 3 0 1 1 4
```

Pero cuando `i` valga 3, el algoritmo detectará el último `1` como duplicado y lo eliminará, dejando la secuencia final como

```
1 3 0 1 0 4
```

---

Volviendo al tema original, que es eliminar duplicados, hay otras formas de actuar.

Así, por ejemplo, puedes usar un contenedor `set` para llevar la cuenta de los números introducidos. El contenedor `set` no admite duplicados, por lo que es un candidato ideal para evitar duplicar valores:

```
std::set<int> numeros;
for( int i=0; i<espacio; i++)
{
    bool nuevo;

    // Tratamos de insertar el elemento en el contenedor
    std::tie(std::ignore, nuevo) = numeros.insert(almacen[i]);

    // Si el numero ya estaba en el almacen, es repetido, lo ponemos a 0
    if (!nuevo)
        almacen[i] = 0;    
}
```

La función `insert` de `set` nos devuelve dos valores:

- Un iterador al valor
- Un booleano que nos indica si el valor es nuevo (true) o si ya existía (false)

Lo que hacemos entonces es descartar el iterador, puesto que no lo necesitamos (para eso usamos `std::ignore`). La función `std::tie` permite coger una tupla y recuperar sus valores en variables individuales. Es una forma simple de recuperar el booleano para manejarlo a nuestro antojo.

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando [aqui](https://wandbox.org/permlink/owtV6B7W5cUHbwyI)

Comment: Llevo rato dando vueltas y no me había percatado sobre la variable aux.

for(int i = 0 ; i < espacio ; i++)
{
    for(int j = i+1 ; j < espacio ; j++)
    {
    }
}

Esto es exactamente lo que quería y no me percataba de cual era el problema. Siempre debo considerar que el valor inferior a I es seguro verdad?.

Gracias por los ej con la funcion insert, todavia no la conocia